# Entity Framework code first with remote database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string, code-first, dbcontext

I am using the Enity Framework code first for my project. It is working fine when I connect to my local system, creating database tables and accessing it correctly but now I am trying to run it on my production server and I am using SQL authentication to connect to db.

When it creates the tables on remote database it uses the username to access these tables, like

```
databasename.username.dbo.tableName
```

but locally those are like

```
databasename.dbo.tableName
```

What should I need to do to access table through Entity framework ?

I also noticed that it created MigrationHistory table in regular tables folder instead of under Systems table.

is this because I am trying to create DB through my local system instead through server ?

please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found the issue, Basically username is the schema name of remote database and after using table annotation and specifying the schema name it fixed the issue.

```
[Table("TableName", Schema= "SchemaName")]
```